# two Java interfaces with same method name but different return types

Tags: java, interface

I have written following java code.

```
interface emp
{
   public void disp1();

}
interface emp1
{
   public int disp1();
}

public class Demo4 implements emp,emp1
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {

   }

@Override
public int disp1() 
   {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
    }
}
```

It is showing me error as - The return type is incompatible with emp.disp1()
And if i change it to void then it says-The return type is incompatible with emp1.disp1()

Can anyone explain me this scenario and the reason behind this error's

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't implement these two interfaces by the same class, since these two methods have the same signature (which means they can't both be implemented in the same class) but not the same return type (which means a single method implementation, regardless of its return type, wouldn't implement both interfaces).